# Uploading Google Cloud Endpoint Client Library in Maven Remote Repository (Nexus)

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-plugin, google-cloud-endpoints

Is there a way to upload the generated cloud endpoint client library in a maven remote repository like Nexus through a mvn goal?

Answer (score 0):

Deploying the endpoints JAR should be pretty simple, just follow the instructions in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/gen_clients#generating_a_client_library_for_android_using_maven).

By step 4 you should have a packed jar file ready to deploy to your repo.